# ufw firewall - how to only "allow" when I am going through a proxy

Tags: linux, firewall, proxy, http-proxy, ufw

I am using a proxy to navigate on internet, and I am trying to setup a firewall that will only let me connect to internet via this proxy:

- if I forgot to turn on the proxy, that I should not be able to connect to internet
- if the proxy was disfunctional (it happened to me with a VPN in the past), then the connection would be cut.

I have done this so far:

```
ufw default deny outgoing
ufw default deny incoming
ufw allow from 149.XXX.XXX.XXX # (the address of the proxy)
ufw allow to 149.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

As soon as I do

```
ufw enable
```

when the proxy is turned off, it does cut all connections.
When I turn on the proxy, the connections are still blocked.
BUT if I disable the firewall:

```
ufw disable
```

then I get prompted with my username and password for the proxy.
Once I have typed these, I can enable the firewall, and all the connections work.

So it works, BUT on my first connection with the proxy I need to disable the firewall, in order to get prompted for credentials.
Is there a way around this?

I guess this indicates that my first connection to the proxy is not a connection "to 149.XXX.XXX.XXX". Why? How can I identify this first connection, in order to "allow" it?

PS: I am using Archlinux, but I don't think it makes any difference for ufw.